# When using the pen tool I can't draw a simple straight line - it doesn't let me just click two points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

When using the pen tool I can't draw a simple straight line - it doesn't let me just click two points.  Basically I click the first point, click a second point and that should be my line - however it doesn't let me end the line there - continues with another anchor point as if making a shape...do i need to uncheck some setting?  Can't figure it out!!

Comment: No if you truly wanted to do what you described youd use the line tool (btw line tool is under appreciated, but it really packs a punch one you discover alt numeric input). Or hit enter. You can also any point exit the pen tool by selecting a different one. Like hittiing a on keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Two quick replies:

1) there is a ***Line*** Tool for simple straight lines to make that fast: see the selected tool below.

2) using the ***Pen*** Tool, once your second point is drawn, click **Esc** and your line is complete.

[image]

Comment: You may want to crop that image a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Press Enter when you see that there's enough clicks done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop adding another point.